# Script runs with ISE but not powershell.exe

Tags: powershell, scripting

After months of "scripting" I finally got my script working as I need it to, except it only does what I want when running it from ISE. When I start it using powershell.exe it throws a fit something about unable to find [system.windows.forms. "dialogresult]".

I have attached the relevant portion of the script, TYIA

```
    $cred = Get-Credential
   $Job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
   Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
   Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing
   $form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
   $form.Text = 'Admin Tools’
   $form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(900,600)
   $form.StartPosition = 'CenterScreen'
   $form.AutoSize = $true
   $form.MaximizeBox = $false
   $form.FormBorderStyle = 'FixedSingle'


   $img = [System.Drawing.Image]::Fromfile("c:\users\$env:username\Pictures\logo.png")
   $pictureBox = New-Object Windows.Forms.PictureBox
   $pictureBox.Width = $img.Size.Width
   $pictureBox.Height = $img.Size.Height
   $pictureBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(600,465)
   $pictureBox.Image = $img
   $form.controls.add($pictureBox) 

   $ADUCButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
   $ADUCButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,25)
   $ADUCButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300,100)
   $ADUCButton.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font(“Times New Roman”,14, [System.Drawing.Fontstyle]::Bold) 
   $ADUCButton.Text = ' Active Directory Users and Computers '
   $ADUCButton.Add_Click({Start-Process -filepath 'c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe' -WindowStyle maximized})
   $ADUCButton.FlatAppearance.BorderColor = [System.Drawing.Color]::DarkBlue
   $ADUCButton.BackColor = [System.Drawing.Color]::CornflowerBlue
   $form.Controls.Add($ADUCButton)

   $label = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
   $label.location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(100,500)
   $label.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,70)
   $label.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Lucida Console",8, 
 [System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Italic)
   $label.Text = 'Created by a PowerShell Novice'
   $form.Controls.Add($label)

   $CancelButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
   $CancelButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(850,300)
   $CancelButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
   $CancelButton.Text = 'Close'
   $CancelButton.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::Cancel
   $form.CancelButton = $CancelButton
   $form.Controls.Add($CancelButton)



   $result = $form.ShowDialog()

   if ($result -eq [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK)
   {
   $x = $listBox.SelectedItems
   $x
   }

   } -Credential $cred
   Recieve-Job $job
```

Any assistance you can provide is greatly appreciated.

Comment: OK, with what you have posted, this has all it needs to work in the ISE, VSCode or in the consolehost. I know this because I just tested your posted code. Also, why are you running this as a job?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are in the ISE it will autoload modules needed to do many things, the consoelhost does not.

If you have form code in your scripts, you must at needed resources, for it to properly run in the consolehost.

Put this at the top of your script. Here is a snippet I keep in for functions

```
# Initialize GUI resources
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing
Add-Type -AssemblyName presentationframework
Add-type -AssemblyName microsoft.VisualBasic
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing

# Required for use with web SSL sites
[Net.ServicePointManager]::
SecurityProtocol = [Net.ServicePointManager]::
                   SecurityProtocol -bor 
                   [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::
                   Tls12
```

You don't need them all, depending on what you are doing or plan to. At the minimum, you need this...

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
```

BTW, this is probably a posting error, but this line is not syntactically correct.

```
if ($result -eq [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult}::OK)
```

It should be this...

```
if ($result -eq [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK)
```

Open/Close bracket type must match

Comment: I will add the full code to provide further context, thank you again...

Comment: I posted the full code, I tried with your suggested edits but PowerShell only prompts for the credentials but doesn't display the form. It continues to work with ISE so there is clearly a line or two that I am missing. 

Thank you for being willing to assist.

Comment: Just leave the form stuff in your job. Again, as noted, I just ran your code on my personal lab on two different machines and it runs as expected. I took out the credential and job sections to narrow the scope of the debug effort. Which means potentially something environmental on your side. Also, this is misspelled [Recieve-Job $job], and should be [Receive-Job $job]

Comment: OK, I can get it to render if I create a new form
$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form

Is there anyway I can either hide this new window or have the $form reference the previously defined $job? I hope you understand the question.

Comment: So, are you saying that you added a new additional line to your code [$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form], that really should not be needed. Yet you say you are getting a rendering. Update your post to show that. As noted, again, your code sample is working on my side without any real alteration other than removing the credential stuff and/or the job stuff.

Comment: I have taken a different approach to coding this, I am trying to now have each button run with the previously saved $cred variable. That does away with the scriptblock. The issue is I do not know how to add that to the syntax that creates the button. With the new approach I can create the form without the code embedded inside the scriptblock brackets.